# Is it possible to accept two equally satisfying answers?

Tags: feature-request

I've posted a question for a single problem, and I've got 2 equally satisfying answers giving me the same result I am looking for.

I know that I can only accept one answer. I've read the answers posted to similar request; and I am hoping you can find a solution for this situation; because both answers satisfy my needs equally.

Comment: this is indeed a conundrum.  of course, you should vote for both -- the fact that you've stayed around and asked this question is appreciated (some people don't).  in this circumstances, i'd leave a comment on both saying that the answer satisfies your needs.  then, i'd probably try to figure out which answer might be more help to other seekers of similar information and vote for that, again with an explanation in a comment.  it's a tough decision.

Comment: Related [How to choose between two equally good and equally helpful answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3587).

Comment: You can give bounties to several different answers, but this takes time and requires some reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that I can only accept one answer

Indeed you can, multiple accepted answers would seem to defeat the purpose of the green tick a bit.

What you could do if you really can't choose between them is democratise the process. You could leave it a few days and see if one collects more votes. That might suggest it was a little bit better explained or a little bit more preferable to a wider audience. Alternatively you could give the tick to the one with fewer votes in order to give it a bit of a signal boost and extra love.

Or you could simply give the tick to whoever got there first.

Or I suppose you could toss a coin.

Generally I'd be more inclined to award a tick for an answer which had a bit more explanation if that applies in your case. Or if the answer came with a screenshot showing the output. Or if the answer added an extra tip. Or maybe the code was simpler. Or, for me personally, I quite like a more primitive answer. Many wise and experienced people advocate the use of packages to do cool things and make your life easier. After all LaTeX is basically just a huge bundle of TeX macros and templates and presets and stuff. But I find an overly big preamble can be awkward, packages can clash, they can go obsolete, they can be updated and break. I quite like the answer that uses basic commands you can find in Leslie Lamport's book, possibly, I'll be honest, for no other reason than because I took the time to read that book and understand them well once :P Perhaps you will prefer an answer like this too, or perhaps you'd rather learn about a cool new package that can save you five or five dozen extra lines of code.

Comment: Or you could simply not accept an answer, if you really think either solution would be equally helpful to you.  While in general it's good to accept answers, I don't think it should be taken as an obligation in all cases.

Comment: @AlanMunn it shouldn't necessarily, but accepting an answer isn't just about awarding 1st prize to an answer. Accepting an answer will take the question off of the unanswered list and will serve to mark the issue as resolved, which is quite useful

Comment: No, the unanswered list only includes questions with no upvoted answers. Questions with upvoted answers even when not accepted don't count as "unanswered".

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh I see! Well, there you go, I didn't know that :) Even so, the fact that there is an accepted answer is something that the site makes an effort to show you, with its green box around the number of answers. So I think marking a question as solved still has some value and is arguably an important function of the tick, perhaps more than awarding one answer a ribbon